# Calculating color combination with hex values

Tags: php, colors, hex, rgb, color-scheme

In additive color mixing primary colors are Red, Green and Blue (RGB).

```
Red    = #ff0000
Green  = #00ff00
Blue   = #0000ff
```

Combining **Red** (`#ff0000`) and **Green** (`#00ff00`) makes **Yellow** (`#ffff00`)

Is there some formula to calulate the hex code of a color resulting from the combination of two others ?

Something like `#ff0000 + #00ff00` when applied to such a formula gives `#ffff00`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add two HEX string like this in PHP:

```
$red = "FF0000";
$green = "00FF00";

$yellow = dechex(hexdec($red) + hexdec($green));

echo $yellow;
```

[**Live Demo**](http://codepad.org/Efwb79xQ)

What that snippet is basically doing is converting the hex strings to numbers, adding them together, and then converting the sum back to a hex string.

Reference Links:

[hexdec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php) |
[dechex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php)

Comment: But you should really separate the three components. Because `"00FF00" + "00FF00"` wouldn't do what you probably want. A sum like this has no meaning.